# generator-jhipster-blueprint "jhContext.setupClientOptions is not a function"

Tags: jhipster, yeoman

I am trying to generate a Jhipster Client Blueprint.

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-blueprint

I am trying to override the client and getting the following error

```
ERROR! jhContext.setupClientOptions is not a function
TypeError: jhContext.setupClientOptions is not a function
    at new module.exports (D:\Code\generator-jhipster-blueprint-generated\generators\client\index.js:19:19)
    at Environment.instantiate (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\environment.js:748:23)
```

Comment: Not really a question for stackoverflow, it's probably a bug similar to https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-blueprint/issues/225 please open a new issue and run under node debugger to get more information